# ORA-02067 error on Spring MVC / Oracle / Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, oracle, transactions, tomcat7

Randomly my Spring MVC/Oracle 11G/Tomcat 7 application is throwing the following error: “ORA-02067: transaction or savepoint rollback required”

Once that error appears ALL subsequent operations to the database that uses that same connection through the Tomcat will fail throwing the ORA-02067 error.

Example:

```
"detailErrorInfo": "CallableStatementCallback; 
uncategorized SQLException for SQL 
[{call SCHEMAX.[PACKAGEX].PROCEDUREX()}]; SQL state [60000]; 
error code [604]; 
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-02067: transaction or savepoint rollback required;
nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: 
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-02067: transaction or savepoint rollback required",
```

Curiously, if I call that same Oracle package/procedure from other connection or application, it works.

The error stops only on the Spring application the moment the administrator restart the Tomcat.

My theory is there is a transaction that is failing and is not doing a rollback. Because the Tomcat is using a pool of JDBC connections, the error persists on the application.

I have not being able to reproduce that on the development environment.

Does Oracle provides tools to pinpoint the culprit transaction?  Is there any view that display transaction that are pending a rollback?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share code of procedure? Contains `SCHEMAX.[PACKAGEX].PROCEDUREX()` any invocation of database link?

Comment: Your theory is correct. Since you are using Spring you could wrap your dataSource with p6spy and look for the PLSQL call. You should also compile the PLSQL production code onto your development env, perhaps compiled proc differs.